# Maven, перенос ресурсов из jar во внешние

Tags: java, maven

Имеется проект со внутренними ресурсами и сборщиком maven, есть ли возможность делать две сборки одного проекта, одну с ресурсами в jar файле, а во второй выносить ресурсы в отдельную папку `resources`, в тот же каталог где хранится jar файл?

Обязательное условие, вторая сборка была полностью работоспособна и использовала внешние ресурсы.

**Edit:**

Директория:

```
 - target
    |_ test.jar
    |_ externalResources
       |_ text.txt
```

Добвил в pom.xml:

```
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>${basedir}/externalResources</directory>
           </resource>
       </resources>

       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.TestMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>externalResources/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <!-- Копирование в папку target файлы из resources в externalResources -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources-1</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/resources/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/externalResources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Вызов ресурса `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("text.txt").getPath();`, но ресурс найти не может.

Comment: Можно сделать два модуля, один собирает так, второй по другому.

Comment: @AlexanderTolstikhin судя по твоему расположению файлов тебе надо получать его таким образом `TestMain.class.getResource("/test.txt").getPath();`, либо добавить в `externalResorce` папку `resources` и уже туда добавить файл `test.txt`

Comment: @Темкатоже проблему это не решило. Добавил pom аннотации для `class-path` в `manifest`. Тоже не помогло. Обновил сообщение.

Comment: 1) вам нужно поменять конфигурацию maven jar plugin для того чтоб он не включал в себя ваши конфигурационные файлы (если этого не сделать есть вероятность что вместо внешних конфиг файлов оно будет использовать те которые лежат внутри jar файла)  

2) сконфигурировать maven resource plugin таким образом чтоб он копировал только нужные вам конфигурационные файлы в нужную папку (похоже это уже сделано)  

3) при запуске приложения вам придется указывать в classpath папку в которой лежать ресурсы (см в ответе @Темкатоже)

Answer (score 1):

Всё довольно просто. Делаешь два профиля. Один со стандартными конфигами, в другом делаешь примерно так

```
<build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[пустая_дирректороия]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
```

После этого получившийся jar'ник, собранный под вторым профилем, тебе надо будет запускать с дополнительной опцией где-то так: `java -cp "./externalResource" -jar myJar.jar`, где `./externalResource` - путь к папке с твоими внешними ресурсами, а `myJar.jar` твой итоговый jar'ник (предпологается, что папка с внешними ресурсами лежит там же, где и jar'ник).

---

**UPDATE**

Как-то я и забыл про про политику загрузки ресурсов) Но решение всё равно есть. Надо подгружать ресурсы через пустой класс, который будет присутствовать в нескольких jar'никах. В итоге надо собирать проект исключая данный класс из всех jar'ников кроме одного. Собственно собрал простенький [проект](http://my-files.ru/Save/q4em2q/questions-475880.zip). В корне есть `run.sh`/`run.bat` для демонстрации.

Comment: В netbeans прописал параметры запуска приложения:
   `-cp  "./externalResource" %classpath com.TestMain`. Ресурс хочу получить так: `TestMain.class.getResource("/resources/test.txt").getPath();`
В папку `target` добавляю папку `externalResource` с файлом `test.txt`. Но получить ресурс не удаётся.

Comment: В прикреплённом проекте мы снова пришли к методу хранения ресурсов в jar файле. Только теперь это отдельный jar файл. Есть ли возможность хранить ресурсы не в jar файле, а в отдельно директории.?